# Understanding Book Proof that $[-2 \pi i x f(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi) = {d \over d\xi} \widehat{f}(\xi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

**Goal:** Show that

$$
[-2 \pi i x f(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi) = {d \over d\xi} \widehat{f}(\xi)
$$

where $\wedge$ denotes the operation of the Fourier Transform:

$$
\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{- 2 \pi i \xi x} f(x) dx
$$

**Proof from Book (with problematic portions highlighted):**

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

**Problem:** It is not apparent to me why the three highlighted portions of this proof are true. That is, it is not apparent to me why, for $|x| > N$ and $h$ small enough, that each line of this inequality holds:

\begin{align*}
\left| [\widehat{f}(\xi + h) - \widehat{f}(\xi)]/h - [-2\pi ixf(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi) \right|
&= \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} \left[ {e^{- 2 \pi i x h} - 1\over h} + 2 \pi i x\right] dx \right| \\
&\le 2\pi \int_{|x|> N} |x| |f(x)| \left| {e^{- 2 \pi i x h} - 1 \over 2 \pi x h} + i \right| dx
\end{align*}

Comment: The first equality in the final display in your post is just the definition of the Fourier transform, applied three times. The final inequality is just the fact that $|\int g|\le\int|g|$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work easier for you instead:
$$
    \frac{e^{-2\pi ixh}-1}{h}+2\pi ix
  = -2\pi i x\left[\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}(e^{-2\pi ixt}-1)dt\right] \\
  = -2\pi ix \left[\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{t}(-2\pi ix)e^{-2\pi ixs}dsdt\right] \\
  = 4\pi^2 x^2\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2\pi ixs}dsdt.
$$

Comment: What justifies the first step in this equation?

Comment: @user1770201 : $e^{-2\pi ixh}-1 = e^{-2\pi i xt}|_{t=0}^{h}=\int_{0}^{h} (-2\pi i x)e^{-2\pi i xt}dt$ and $2\pi ix = -2\pi ix \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^{h}(-1)dt$.