# Expanding $\left| [\widehat{f}( \xi + h) - \widehat{f}( \xi)]/h - [- 2 \pi i f(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi) \right|$ into one integral

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, exponential-function, harmonic-analysis

In the context of Fourier Analysis, I'm having trouble why, as a lemma to [another proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606451/understanding-book-proof-that-2-pi-i-x-fx-wedge-xi-d-over-d-xi), that

$$
\left| [\widehat{f}( \xi + h) - \widehat{f}( \xi)]/h - [- 2 \pi i x f(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi)  \right| 
= \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{- 2 \pi i x \xi}  \left[{e^{- 2 \pi i x h} - 1\over h} + 2 \pi i x\right] dx \right|
$$

**Attempt.** I have computed the following:

1. $\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} f(x) dx$
2. $\widehat{f}(\xi + h) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2 \pi i x (\xi + h)} f(x) dx$
3. $[-2 \pi i x f(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{- 2 \pi i x \xi} \left( -2 \pi i x f(x) \right) dx$

Then

\begin{align*}
&\ \ \ \ \  \ \left| [\widehat{f}( \xi + h) - \widehat{f}( \xi)]/h - [- 2 \pi i x f(x)]^{\wedge}(\xi)  \right| \\
&= {\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2 \pi i x (\xi + h)} f(x) dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} f(x) dx \over h} - \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{- 2 \pi i x \xi} \left( -2 \pi i x f(x) \right) dx
\end{align*}

From here it is not clear how to assemble this into the integral above.

Comment: The result is wrong as stated. The correct one is in the linked page. The result should be really easy, relying only on the linearity of the integral. Try it again and be careful.

Comment: On reflection I don't even see how it is possible for this question to receive an answer that is anything more than "use linearity". If you want an answer, I suggest you fully type out your attempt; then the mistake can be pointed out.